# liferay on tomcat don't load a class

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, liferay

I'm making a portlet on Liferay deployed on jboss. Today I changed a library and starts to happens a problem. When I deploy a portlet I have to restart Liferay otherwise I have this exception:

```
17:09:36,325 ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:554] Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResources(WebappClassLoader.java:1245)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4.run(LogFactory.java:1317)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getResources(LogFactory.java:1336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getConfigurationFile(LogFactory.java:1398)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:417)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
    at org.springframework.security.portlet.PortletAuthenticationDetails.(PortletAuthenticationDetails.java:14)
```

This morning I had a similar problem when i tried to use the Logger of log4j...and now this problem is with the common log...someone can help me?

Comment: What library have you changed?

Comment: it's own library...someone make some modify but i don't know what...

Comment: Right... And how did you replace it? Did you put a new jar in the lib directory of the portlet? Or is the new library at the lib dir of the server?

Comment: i put the jar in the lib directory...the strange thing is that it seems a problem of log4j

Answer (score 0):

i think you met a bug in Tomcat. because it should not throw a RuntimeException especially NullPointerException. how to deal with it? read the source code of tomcat at line 1245...